# How to automatically update Slicer in Power Bi to Today's Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having a power Bi Report which has a slicer the date column is coming from SQL.
I have Current months Dates till 28-june-2022 and Last years dates in Sql till 30 June 2021

I want only Values to be displayed for todays date in the 2021 Slicer and not all the dates till 30

Screenshot of the Slicer is below

I don't want the Yellow Dates I want the dates to get added automatically when i refresh the other day.

I can do this manually  with a filter which is not feasible

[image]

Comment: I am trying the below DAX Funcation but still not getting the result Result = if(Table[DATE.1]<Today(),"True","False")

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want a list of dates within the date range of today and last-year's today. That is the same as the last 12 months of dates. You can do this in the filter pane:

[image]

Be sure to un-check the 'Include Today' option.

Another option to select a list of dates between any set of dates is with a measure. Use the following measure to define whatever range of dates you would like. I have done the last full year of dates as an example:

```
DAX_Dates = 
CALCULATE(COUNT('Date'[Date]) --Counts number of records
    ,KEEPFILTERS( --Allows the filter context of the visuals to dynamically evaluate the calculation
        DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date] --Defines a range of dates to apply the calculation
            ,DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())) --Start Date
            ,TODAY() --End Date
        )
    )
)
```

Next, you can filter the visual with the measure.
[image]

Comment: @Clifforod Piehl Basically my Dates are coming from and SQL table and there are already 30 Days in June 2022 I only want Dates to be displayed will Todays Date say 28-june-2022

Comment: Added another solution with an edit. Does this help?